# Is there a way to view a comment's source?

Tags: feature-request, comments, view-source

Sometimes (old) comments break the parser, so it would be nice to view their code to check what was (actually) supposed to be there. Is there any way to view a comment's source just like the source link in a post's revision?

**edit** Another application for this would be the ability to better quote comments in an answer without having to re-markdown them.

Comment: Got an example?

Comment: I guess you could view the page source and look at the raw HTML?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - It will show the output in the page source too not the actual source we are looking for.

Comment: @Bart: Just try anything with more than one consecutive backtick, backslash or asterisk; examples should be fairly easy to make.

Comment: For what I understand of the system, either this is a [tag:feature-request] or we need a [custom script](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script) to "de-parse" the HTML.

Comment: @Bart It's not necessarily restricted to broken display, another reason might be a comment containing some formatting, links or code which one wants to quote in an answer/question without having to reformat everything again...

Comment: @brasofilo Well, if this is currently not possible, I'd indeed re-tag this into a request

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, I misread. I thought we were talking about old comments no longer displaying right.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/ ? It's not as easy as it could be, but I don't think enough people need to see this often enough that it has to be easy.

Comment: @Dukeling Come on, I implicitly meant "intuitive"...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler that's [very intuitive](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/145005/view-comments-per-post) - just put the desired post ID and you have all comments listed with their raw source.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Maybe I'm just too dumb, but if I try that with this post's ID (203390) I get an empty list - or does this take several hours to update? **edit** Apparently yes, it works for e.g. 180325

Comment: @TobiasKienzler the data explorer updates once a week.

Comment: An example of use - accessing the tex on such an enabled site to easily pull it into a question or answer post.

Comment: @MichaelT Indeed, especially if interspersed with text such that otherwise many show-source-right-clicks were necessary

Comment: I will add link to [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3234#16530) which mentions a bookmarklet which copies the comments on *a question* with MathJax and MarkDown. The link in the answer is dead, but the bookmarklet is currently available here: https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/

Comment: @Martin Thanks, you could post that as an answer though

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I have asked the user who created it whether they would be willing to post the answer: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5850989#5850989 (I'd say it would be better if the author of the bookmarklet posted the answer.) If he doesn't, feel free to post some basic info about the bookmarklet as answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [Tim's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203440/152859), I have constructed [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/145005/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url).

You can put either the comment ID, or the raw comment URL and get its full details, including the raw source as requested.

To get the comment URL, middle click or right click and choose "Copy link address" over the comment timestamp:

> [image]

For example, the above will result in such a link: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203390/is-there-a-way-to-view-a-comments-source#comment648179_203390`

Now you can either type 648179 in the CommentId text field, or the full link in the RawLink textbox.

For easy copying you might want to run run the Query with the option [Text-only results](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/743625/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url?CommentId=648179+&RawLink=null&opt.textResults=true) enabled so it becomes easier to copy the raw results.

Note, the SEDE data is updated on a weekly basis, every Sunday or Monday so comments posted in the last week after Sunday or Monday won't show up.

Comment: I'm not sure this works anymore? I tried with a comment from ELL meta and it didn't output anything.

Comment: @Fiksdal yes is still works. [Example from ELL meta](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.ell/query/145005/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url?CommentId=8844). What comment exactly did you try?

Comment: [This comment.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/why-this-question-of-mine-got-so-many-viewers/3220?noredirect=1#comment8940_3219)

Comment: @Fiksdal you missed the last paragraph in my answer: "the SEDE data is updated on a weekly basis".

Comment: Ah, thanks :D Got it.

Comment: In case someone is wondering how to get the complete text without downloading the CSV file, you can resize the text column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OTLs.png

Answer (score 14):

You can either use [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) or the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com)'s [`/comments/{ids}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-by-ids) with [the `body_markdown` filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-by-ids#order=desc&sort=creation&ids=648164&filter=!9f8L750Tb&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true) to get the source of a given comment. Going with one of these options would make more sense than having native site functionality, since this isn't really a common use case.

It's also not *too* difficult to reverse-engineer the appropriate Markdown based on the resulting HTML source (I have something similar for chat messages from back when I did the Town Hall Digests), but obviously that takes a bit more work than the above-mentioned methods. Plus, when considering edge-cases related to bug reports, the reverse-engineered Markdown may not be identical to the source.

Answer (score 6):

There is a User Script in this answer [Converting a comment to an answer (again)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/286244) which adds a "Source" link to comments:

[image]

When you click the link it displays the source in a popup:

[image]

This text can be copied and pasted elsewhere ...