# Is there a list of app functionality that is not on the web site?

Tags: support, ios-app

Regarding question: [Converting a comment to an answer (again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286234/converting-a-comment-to-an-answer-again)
and the comment following it:

Is there a list of iOS (or other) app functions that are not available on the SE web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

The closest you get now is querying for all questions that have three tags: [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). If you combine those, you will see most features requested by users. Features introduced by the team can't be found that way.

Here is the [list of posts matching that filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+feature-request+status-completed).