# How can I easily access the markdown text of a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, data-explorer

So the query in the answer to the question this has been closed against has exactly the same problem as the query I mentioned in my question - I can't actually see more than the first few words of the comment in the output!

Sometimes I want to copy a carefully formatted and/or link-loaded comment, but, unlike with posts, I can't click anything to show me the markdown text, so all the formatting has to be re-done.

I found [this useful query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/230311/show-text-of-specific-comment) which does print the markdown text, but I have to download the CSV to see the whole comment.

Could I format the output of that query to include the whole markdown text of the comment (nicely wrapped :) )? Or is there another way to access the markdown text of comments? Is there a userscript for this?

Comment: I wrote a userscript to do this here: [Converting a comment to an answer (again)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/286244) (a few people have reported it not working but I use it daily on a bunch of browsers/OSs etc)

Comment: @Cai thanks that's exactly what I want (although it's not working for me right now) (just commenting here for reviewers since I edited my post after closure, sorry for double ping)

Comment: try http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/743625/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url?CommentId=648179+&RawLink=null&opt.textResults=true as I enabled textResults on that one. If you run it, you don't end up in the slickgrid, but just the raw results. You still need to do some scrolling but you can copy the complete text without having to do the download as csv step.

Comment: In [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/145005/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url), you don't have to download the CSV file to see the whole comment, you can resize the Text column so that the whole text fits in it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OTLs.png.

Comment: @DonaldDuck you're obviously writing shorter comments than me XD

Comment: User script - [Converting a comment to an answer (again)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/286244) - adds a source link to comments.

Comment: I would have answered this question but someone closed it :/ See [my answer to the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302175/267099) instead ;)